# Install softwares on other partitions

Tags: macos, install, partition, r

I have partitioned my HD in three parts, system, work and private.
I was trying to install R in work volume but it failed because it could find OS?

So is it necessary to install all SWs on system, or there is a way to allow me install in that volume 'work'.

Answer (score 1):

In general, OS X applications can run from anywhere. Depending on which R distribution you install it might run just fine from an Application bundle or you will just have to adjust your $PATH variable to place the executable files where they can be found.

You probably have a more specific install error that's causing your issues. Perhaps listing the exact version of R and where you got it / what steps you are following would allow us to help you better. *(Ideally you would list the OS on Mac and the exact error message or what you are seeing that makes you think the installation failed.)*

Comment: I tried to install R 3.0.2. So I have to set up the $path variable? During installing, the error message sent by installer said cannot find OS X. I guess it will also be an issue for MacTex?